# RapidSQL Shortcuts

Tags: sql, rapidsql

I'm using RapidSQL 7.3.3 on a project and can't find any documentation on shortcuts. 
I'm just looking for the general things like commenting out a number of lines at once and anything else that would spead my work up.

If anyone knows a resourse or just shortcuts themselves I'd be greatful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're available in the [RapidSQL user guide](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rapid_sql/rs7.5/Rapidsql_user_guide.pdf) starting on page 53;

> Keyboard Shortcuts
>
> Rapid SQL provides a number of keyboard shortcuts to help you expedite your tasks.
> The table below lists the taxes and related shortcuts:
>
> Delete one character to the left **BACKSPACE**
> Delete one character to the right **DELETE**
> ...and so on...